# electron-webpack-react error "Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@'"

Tags: reactjs, webpack, electron

I'm using Electron, Webpack and React on this project. When I try to build the project, I end up with this error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
@keyframes
```

The error always points to a specific .css file that is inside a node_modules folder, and the error occurs at this point:

```
@keyframes activeSwitchCircleAnimation {
 from {
    left: 0;
 } to {
    left: 14px; }
 }

@keyframes deactiveSwitchCircleAnimation {
 from {
    left: 14px;
 } to {
    left: 0; }
 }
```

I've already looked through a bunch of "unexpected character '@'" error questions, and most of them point towards errors occuring at .sass or .scss files, which is not the case here.

This is the webpack config file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const BabiliPlugin = require('babili-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')

const defaultInclude = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          'postcss-loader'
        ],
        include: defaultInclude
      },
      {
        test: /(\.scss|\.sass)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          'postcss-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ],
        include: defaultInclude
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        use: [{ loader: 'babel-loader' }],
        include: defaultInclude
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/,
        use: [{ loader: 'file-loader?name=img/[name]__[hash:base64:5].[ext]' }],
        include: defaultInclude
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        use: [{ loader: 'file-loader?name=font/[name]__[hash:base64:5].[ext]' }],
        include: defaultInclude
      }
    ]
  },
  target: 'electron-renderer',
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'bundle.css',
      chunkFilename: '[id].css'
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
    }),
    new BabiliPlugin()
  ],
  stats: {
    colors: true,
    children: false,
    chunks: false,
    modules: false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the `include: defaultInclude` and then put a entry point. Your webpack.config file should be like this:

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const BabiliPlugin = require('babili-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')

const defaultInclude = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')

module.exports = {
  entry: defaultInclude,
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          'postcss-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /(\.scss|\.sass)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          'postcss-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        use: [{ loader: 'babel-loader' }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/,
        use: [{ loader: 'file-loader?name=img/[name]__[hash:base64:5].[ext]' }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        use: [{ loader: 'file-loader?name=font/[name]__[hash:base64:5].[ext]' }]
      }
    ]
  },
  target: 'electron-renderer',
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'bundle.css',
      chunkFilename: '[id].css'
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
    }),
    new BabiliPlugin()
  ],
  stats: {
    colors: true,
    children: false,
    chunks: false,
    modules: false
  }
}
```